# Suggestions on text input in Redux-form

Tags: reactjs, field, redux-form

I have done quite a bit of searching but I havent found the solution I hoped for.

My goal is to show suggestions to user when he starts typing in the text input. Say I have an array of names that will be suggested. I suppose there will be an onChange handler but Im not sure how to implement this efficiently.

I am grateful for any suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Baically, what you need to do is to create some kind of `<AuotoComplete />` input component (or - what one would usually do - use some third party component libary which will provide this functionality out of the box. For example [material-ui](https://v0.material-ui.com/#/components/auto-complete), [react-select](https://react-select.com/home), [react-autosuggest](https://react-autosuggest.js.org/) etc.).

Then you will need to deligate `redux-form`'s `<Field />`'s `onChange` and `value` props to this component in order for it to update your `redux-form` reducer.

The implementation should look something like this:

```
   <Field
      name="fieldName"
      component={({ input: { value, onChange } }) => (
        <AutoComplete value={value} onChange={onChange} />
      )}
    />
```

[Here's a working example I created with `material-ui`'s `AutoComplete`.](https://codesandbox.io/s/9y5jozyo8y)

(Bear in mind that I used `redux-form-material-ui` which abstracts the delegation of the `onChange` and `value` and allows you to use all of material-ui's `AutoComlete`'s props streight on `redux-form`'s `<Field/>`)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This looks really nice, Im going to try that. Thank you sir :)

Answer (score 0):

How you could approach it, is to fetch all the array data by dispatching an redux action `getNamesArray` and then use the filter and map functions in the component:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.getNamesArray();
}

render(){
  const { namesArray } = this.props; // from redux mapStateToProps
  let namesArrayItems;

  if (namesArrayItems.length > 0) {
    namesArrayItems = namesArray
      .filter(name => {
        // remove names that do not match current filter text
        return name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.name.toLowerCase()) >= 0
      })
      .map(name=> (
        <NameItem key={name._id} name={name} />
      ));
    } else {
      namesArrayItems = <h4>No Names found...</h4>;
        }
  return (
    {namesArrayItems}
  );
}
```

Then use a text field input that is passed above as `this.state.name` by using an onChange handler to get user input:

```
onChange(e) {
  this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
}
```

And in the return put and text field with the onChange handler:

```
<input
  type="text"
  name="name"
  value={this.state.name}
  placeholder="Filter Names"
  onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
/>
```

Works fairly efficient for me. The downside to this approach is that you first fetch all your array data, so this make take longer loading times, however the application does not need to fetch data with each user input, making the user experience more seamless.